# How to catch EINTR in Python?

Tags: python, linux, exception, signals

My issue is caused (if I'm not wrong) by EINTR signal that cause raise of error while system call like select is performed. This issue is everywhere on the internet and there are solutions that are well described but all of them are not working for me.
In multithread application I use many select calls (I have TCP server and separately TCP client), when I call system lock (my appliaction do that, by gnome-screensaver-commands -lock) random select throws:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/home/aziemek/Desktop/Zablokowanie uśpienia/server.py", line 45, in run
inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select([self.server],[],[],TIME_TO_CHECK/2)
error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

This is how I try to cach EINTR:

```
try:
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select([self.client],[],[],TIME_TO_CHECK*2) 
except EnvironmentError as why:
    print("Blad ta :" + str(why.args[0]))
    if why.args and why.args[0] != EINTR:
        print("Error during server loop" + why)
    else:
        continue
except socket.error as why:
    print("Blad ta :" + str(why.args[0]))
    if why.args and why.args[0] != EINTR:
        raise
    else:
        continue
except Exception as why:
    print("Blad to :" + str(why.args[0]))
except:
    print("Blad niewiadomy")
```

None of "except" clauses can catch this exception - even last two. System: Linux Ubuntu, Python 2.6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to catch `OSError, select.error`:

```
import select
# ...

except (OSError, select.error) as why:
    # ...
```

`OSError` so you are forward compatible; your traceback is dealing with `select.error`.